# How is R able to sum an integer sequence so fast?

Tags: r, performance, sum

Create a large contiguous sequence of integers:

```
x <- 1:1e20
```

How is R able to compute the `sum` so fast?

```
sum(x)
```

Doesn't it have to loop over 1e20 elements in the vector and sum each element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summing up the comments:

R introduced something called ALTREP, or ALternate REPresentation for R objects. Its intent is to do some things more efficiently. From https://www.r-project.org/dsc/2017/slides/dsc2017.pdf, some examples include:

- allow vector data to be in a memory-mapped file or distributed
- allow compact representation of arithmetic sequences;
- allow adding meta-data to objects;
- allow computations/allocations to be deferred;
- support alternative representations of environments.

The second and fourth bullets seem appropriate here.

We can see a hint of this in action by looking at what I'm inferring is at the core of the R `sum` primitive for altreps, at https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/7c0449d81c853f781fb13e9c7118065aedaf2f7f/src/main/altclasses.c#L262:

```c
static SEXP compact_intseq_Sum(SEXP x, Rboolean narm)
{
#ifdef COMPACT_INTSEQ_MUTABLE
    /* If the vector has been expanded it may have been modified. */
    if (COMPACT_SEQ_EXPANDED(x) != R_NilValue) 
    return NULL;
#endif
    double tmp;
    SEXP info = COMPACT_SEQ_INFO(x);
    R_xlen_t size = COMPACT_INTSEQ_INFO_LENGTH(info);
    R_xlen_t n1 = COMPACT_INTSEQ_INFO_FIRST(info);
    int inc = COMPACT_INTSEQ_INFO_INCR(info);
    tmp = (size / 2.0) * (n1 + n1 + inc * (size - 1));
    if(tmp > INT_MAX || tmp < R_INT_MIN)
    /**** check for overflow of exact integer range? */
    return ScalarReal(tmp);
    else
    return ScalarInteger((int) tmp);
}
```

Namely, the reduction of an integer sequence without gaps is trivial. It's when there are gaps or `NA`s that things become a bit more complicated.

In action:

```r
vec <- 1:1e10
sum(vec)
# [1] 5e+19
sum(vec[-10])
# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 37.3 Gb
### win11, R-4.2.2
```

Where ideally we would see that `sum(vec) == (sum(vec[-10]) + 10)`, but we cannot since we can't use the optimization of sequence-summing.

Comment: Some additional reading: [Preview: ALTREP promises to bring major performance improvements to R](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/09/altrep-preview.html), and links therein, e.g. [ALTREP: Alternative Representations for R Objects](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/ALTREP/ALTREP.html)

Comment: Tangentially related:  I was going to try summing  `seq(1, 1e10, by = 2)`  but R exits with the subjective error  " argument "by" is much too small"  .   :-)